# new in jquery: how can i submit form separatly in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

This a standard form submitter in jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {  
        var fname = $('#fname').attr('value');  
        var lname = $('#lname').attr('value');  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "report.php",  
            data: "fname="+ fname +"& lname="+ lname,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){ 
                    $('div.success').show();
                });    
            }
        });  

        return false;  
    });
}); 
</script>
```

and here are the forms:

```
<form id="submit" name="submit">
<input id="fname" name="fname" size="20" type="hidden" value="aword">  <font class='black'>report:</font>
<input id="lname" name="lname" size="40" type="text">  
<button id="send">send</button>
</form>

<form id="submittwo" name="submittwo">
<input id="fname" name="fname" size="20" type="hidden" value="anoterword">  <font class='black'>report:</font>
<input id="lname" name="lname" size="40" type="text">  
<button id="send">send</button>
</form>
```

report.php:

```
<?php
$fname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));  
$lname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));  
$myFile = "reports.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "\n".$fname."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $lname."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fwrite($fh, $theData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

There will be more forms looped with PHP. What I want to do is to submit them separately. Any idea how or can you tell me where I can find an answer?

Comment: use `submit` on each form separately i guess :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iff i have understood the question well this can help

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behaviour of the form submit

    var fname = $("#fname",this).val(); // get the fname of the submitted form
    var lname = $("#lname",this).val(); // get the lname of the submitted form
    $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "report.php",  
            data: "fname="+ fname +"& lname="+ lname,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){
                    $('div.success').show();
                });    
            }
        });  
    });
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fG8T3/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one form, but change the names of your fields

```
<form id="submit" name="submit">
   <input id="fname" name="fname[]" size="20" type="hidden" value="aword">  
   <input id="lname" name="lname[]" size="40" type="text">

   <input id="fname" name="fname[]" size="20" type="hidden" value="anoterword"> 
   <input id="lname" name="lname[]" size="40" type="text">
   <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Now you can iterate through the GET data as an array:

```
foreach ($_GET['fname'] as $index => $value)
{
   echo $_GET['fname'][$index].' '.$_GET['lname'][$index];
}
```

Note: ID's should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear where you're having the problem but if you're trying to submit them without leaving the current page you may be looking for the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started). It makes it a bit easier to submit forms and display the results so you won't be doing it manually as you are in the code you posted.